# How to process data from Servlet independently?

Tags: java, servlets, queue

I have developed the following program/architecture:

A) A Java servlet receives POST requests, gets the Parameters from the POST requests and stores them in a public static LinkedList:

```
public static LinkedList incomingQueue = new LinkedList<myObjects>();
```

That is, for every POST request I do this:

```
incomingQueue.push(myObject);
```

Now, I want to periodically access the Queue and perform processing on the Objects:

```
while(true){
doProcessing(incomingQueue);
wait(someTime);
}
```

Obviously, I don't have a main class to do this. How do I create such a class that has access to the  incomingQueue *without* being triggered by the servlet? What is the correct architecture to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ignoring the fact hat you're using an non-synchronized LinkedList which isn't safe for concurrent access, you would need to create a Thread that ran in the background and handled that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the queue should be placed in servlet context attributes (see: [`ServletContext.setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). Also access to this queue must be synchronized, consider [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).

In plain servlets you can use [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) by starting a thread in `contextInitialized()` and interrupting it in `contextDestroyed`.

If you are using [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) you can use [`@Scheduled` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled), in [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb): `TimerService` or [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

Finally there is a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class in standard Java. Last but not least, have a look at [jms](/questions/tagged/jms), it might be a better choice in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Use a scheduling library like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)
2. If you don't want to use a separate library, you should add a Listener to your `web.xml` that extends [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and starts a separate thread on `contextInitialized()`.

Also: Note the comment by @BrianRoach. The point about the synced list is rather important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize your methods for concurrent access.

A very hard core solution would be to implement it like producer and consumer. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Example_in_Java) is an example that uses stack and 1 producer and 3 consumers.

Much neater solution would be to use [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/).